# More descriptive error messages for Django Serializers?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am deserializing JSON data from file to a model object. I'm using a Django Rest Framework serializer.

The JSON is quite large and I expected some fields that needed tweaking. However, the error messages are not helpful, contrary to those in the docs.

The serializer:

```
class ChannelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Channel
        fields = '__all__'
```

The test:

```
class UnitTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def testDeserializeChannel(self):
        json = Path(Dirs.CHANNELS_METADATA_TEST, 'A SIMULATED REALITY/youtube/A SIMULATED REALITY.json')
        with open(json, 'rb') as file:
            stream = io.BytesIO(file.read())
            parsed_channel = JSONParser().parse(stream)

        serializer = ChannelSerializer(data=parsed_channel, many=True)
        if not serializer.is_valid():  # required for serializer.save() to work
            print(serializer.error_messages, "\n")
            print(serializer.errors)

        channel = serializer.validated_data.save()
        self.assertEqual(channel[0].title, "A SIMULATED REALITY")
        self.assertEqual(channel[0].original_url, "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBT3VPJlhJHeIvmDadeZB5w")
```

The error messages:

```
{'required': 'This field is required.', 'null': 'This field may not be null.', 'not_a_list': 'Expected a list of items but got type "{input_type}".', 'empty': 'This list may not be empty.', 'max_length': 'Ensure this field has no more than {max_length} elements.', 'min_length': 'Ensure this field has at least {min_length} elements.'} 

{'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Expected a list of items but got type "dict".', code='not_a_list')]}
```

We can see `required` and `null` errors but without mentioning of the fields.

I suspect the '**all**' bit in the serializer is the cause, contrary to explicitly defined field. Can somebody comfirm? And more importantly, can it be fixed?

Kr,

Answer (score 1):

You can use DRF's APIException to create your custom exceptions:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException

class MyCustomException(APIException):
    status_code = 400
    default_detail = 'This serializer is not valid my friend...'
    default_code = 'bad_request'
```

Usage:

```py
. . .

if not serializer.is_valid():
    raise MyCustomException()

. . .
```

Outcome if serializer is not valid:

```
"detail": {"This serializer is not valid my friend..."}
```

Like this you can use custom exceptions all around your code. :)

Comment: Thanks, actually the errors are not that bad, only when you create models and don't know modelling well.. I was learning by trial and error and bumped for a while with this :)